# После редактирования JSON файл нечитаем

Tags: python, json, функции

Изначально содержимое файла было

```
data = {}
data[''] = []
with open(storage_path, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

Потом делаю такое:

```
def write(key, value):
    with open(storage_path, 'r+') as f:
        data = dict(json.load(f))
        data[key] = []
        data[key].append(value)
        json.dump(data, f)

write('babah', 'allah')
```

Получаю ошибку после попытки

```
with open(storage_path, 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
print(data)
```

json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 9 (char 8)

Answer (score 0):

```
def write(key, value):
    with open(storage_path, 'r+') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        data[key] = []
        data[key].append(value)
        f.seek(0)
        json.dump(data, f)
```

Comment: не хватает f.truncate() после f.seek(0) (на случай когда новые данные меньше места занимают)

Comment: Как быть если мне нужно записать в файл данные и если в том случае если файл существует то считать его, а если файла нету то записать в новый?

Comment: если у вас новый вопрос, то задайте его как отдельный Stack Overflow вопрос. Явно укажите ввод, вывод и что вместо этого получаете.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы не путаться с записью в файл, можно функции-обёртки из pathlib использовать:

```
import json
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('data.json')
data = json.loads(path.read_text())
data[key] = [value]  # replace list
path.write_text(json.dumps(data))
```